# Azure Devops Permissions - What if a user with Basic level access is added to Readers group of project?

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to understand how permissions work in Azure DevOps in regards to Organization Access level vs. Group Membership within a project. If a user set to access level "Basic" at the org level is added to the Readers group of the project, what can they do? Does their organization level access (Basic) override the project level group permissions, or are they limited to read permissions within the project?

I've gone through the various MS docs and have not found anything that covers this.

Answer (score 0):

Access level and permissions are different security mechanisms but when there is a 'conflict', the more restrictive rule wins.

If a feature is not in a user's access level there will be no access to that feature regardless of the permissions set. E.g., you can't grant access to "Test Case Management" to a "Basic" access level user via permissions. The user's access level must be changed to "Basic + Test Plans".

If a feature is in a user's access level but the relevant permissions are set to `Deny` they won't be able to use the feature.

Also at play is the scope e.g. organization versus project. Access level is organization wide. The Readers group of a project is specific to a project.

If a user with a "Basic" access level has access to a project and the access is only by being a member of the `Readers` group of the project (i.e. the user is not in `Contributors` and not in an administrators group) then the user will have only `Readers` access to the project.